# How to shutdown remote AVD headless emulator from command line on window 7?

Tags: automated-testing

I'm trying to handle AVD headless emulator from command line on window 7. I start AVD emulator with command:

`"emulator -avd emulator -no-audio -no-window"`

and then i try to shut it down by closing command prompt, using command:

`"adb kill-server", "adb reboot -bootloader", "android -s emulator -emu kill"`

But it still keeps on running.

Please help me!
Best Regards!

Comment: has any of the given solutions worked for you? If yes, it would be good to accept an answer so that the question doesn't remain in the unanswered list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command doesn't kill the server, that is the server doesn't turn off, then open the task manager and go to the Processes tab. In the Processes tab look for the process **adb.exe** and kill/close/end that process and viola, your server will shutdown/close/stop.

**OR**

In command prompt,

1. change directory to c:\windows\systen32.
2. Run the command `tasklist`. You will get the list of tasks running.
3. Note down the PID of the task you want to kill.
4. Run this command - `Taskkill /PID [you task's pid] /F`
5. to kill multiple tasks run the command with space separated PIDs - `Taskkill /PID [you task's pid] [you task's pid] [you task's pid]  /F`

Happy Testing :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now, I want to code automation test, so i wanna call start or shut down emulator by using command line. When i run start emulator headless again, there is one emulator created ( have 2 emulator headless). Are there any way to shut down it by using command line? Best Regards!

Comment: Well to kill the emulators from command line you'll have to use the commands you've mentioned in the question. At least that's what the Android's site says - "http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html". If that doesn't work you can try the other method mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command:

> adb -e emu kill

Comment: Hey Seth, while this might be exactly what OP needs, I think we can both agree that blindly copying command lines off a post is bad for future visitors. Could you explain what the parameters mean, so future people who land here can determine if this command is right for them? Thanks!

Comment: I tried with command: "adb -e emu kill" but nothing happened.

Comment: command worked for me!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ adb -e emu kill
```

worked for me, I want create a bash script for my CI to 1st start an emulator before compiling the project then killing the emulator after it has been completed